# Login form validation in android

Tags: java, android, validation

I have developed one login form in Android. I have used validation here. I have to fill anyone (username or password) then my app should display *Success!* and should move to other activity.

But, if both fields are empty, the success message should not be displayed and it should display *Login fail!!!*.

Please help me this.

**This is my webservice code:**

```
public class XcartLogin {
    public String authentication(String userName, String password) {
        String retrievedUserName = "";
        String retrievedPassword = "";
        String status = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart432-pro", "root", "");
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers WHERE login = '" + userName + "'");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                retrievedUserName = result.getString("login");
                retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
            }
            if (retrievedUserName.equals(userName) && retrievedPassword.equals(password)) {
                status = "Success!";
            } else {
                status = "Login fail!!!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

**This is validation for my android code:**

```
if(status.equals("Success!"))
    {
        // ADD  to save  and  read next time
        String strUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
        String strPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0)
        {
            // showToast("Enter Your Name");
            userName.setError( "username is required!" );
            isUserValidated = false;
        }
        if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0)
        {
            // showToast("Enter Your Password");
            isPasswordValidated = false;
            userPassword.setError( "password is required!" );
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Just off the topic.. The above form of code is very much susceptible for SQL injection & you should never retreive the password back from DB instead pass it as paramater to SQL prepared statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try using this condition:**

```
if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)&&!(retrievedUserName.equals("") && retrievedPassword.equals("")))
```

**Instead of your condition:**

```
if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password))
```

Comment: and even as Sujay suggested change the prepared statement.
your's is a wrong usage of a prepared statement

Answer (score 3):

Before the `if(status.equals("Success!"))` statement in your validation code, you should do this first to avoid querying the database if any of the text fields are empty in the first place:

```
boolean errorOccurred = false;
if (strUserName.equals("")) {
    userName.setError("Username is required!");
    errorOccurred = true;
}

if (strPassword.equals("")) {
    userName.setError("Password is required!");
    errorOccurred = true;
}

if (errorOccurred) {
    return; // avoids executing the part of your code which queries the db
}
```

Checking for whether the input fields' values are `null` is quite pointless since if they don't contain anything, it will only be an empty string, or `""`. Then, to simplify your webservice code...

```
if (result.next()) { // use if instead of while, because ideally, only ONE record should
                     // be returned and hence, no need to loop;

    // then, just get the corresponding password
    retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
}

if (retrievedPassword.equals(password)) {
    status = "Success!";
}
```

Further suggestion: put "Success!" in a `String` constant and use that instead of the literal value. You have lesser chances of committing mistakes this way and makes editing your code easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way you're using the PreparedStatement is incorrect. Here's how you should modify it:

```
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers WHERE login = ?");
```

You would then use the `setString(int paramIndex, String value)` to set the value and then call the `executeQuery()` method. Something like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers WHERE login = ?");
statement.setString(1, userName);

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

This is secure and the actual way to use a PreparedStatement in your code.

Now, to test for your requirement, you should do something like this:

```
if(userName.equals(retrievedUserName)&&password.equals(retrievedPassword)&&!("".equals(retrievedUserName) && "".equals(retrievedPassword)))
```

Notice that I am checking *userName* and *password* against *retrievedUserName* and *retrievedPassword* and **not** the other way round because there *retrievedUserName* or *retrievedPassword* may be null as per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29) for `getString(int)`.

> Returns: the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value
>   returned is null

If the value were to come as null, then you would be dealing with a `NullPointerException`, which I guess you might want to avoid. Also, for the very same reason, you might want to check the arguments for null value as before you even try to query the database.